# Spark Application Failing when deployed on Dataproc cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have any application running successfully when ran it locally, then i have built a jar and deployed it to GCP and tried running it on data proc cluster, but it is failing with some exception, which i am not sure of, here is the stack trace from error log.

```
20/08/19 15:58:07 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @4444ms
    20/08/19 15:58:07 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT, build timestamp: unknown, git hash: unknown
    20/08/19 15:58:07 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server: Started @4520ms
    20/08/19 15:58:07 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@6015a4a5{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:35581}
    20/08/19 15:58:08 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at fc-available-picked-ingestor-m/10.22.166.101:8032
    20/08/19 15:58:08 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at fc-available-picked-ingestor-m/10.22.166.101:10200
    20/08/19 15:58:08 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
    20/08/19 15:58:08 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
    20/08/19 15:58:08 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.ResourceUtils: Adding resource type - name = memory-mb, units = Mi, type = COUNTABLE
    20/08/19 15:58:08 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.ResourceUtils: Adding resource type - name = vcores, units = , type = COUNTABLE
    20/08/19 15:58:10 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1597777222711_0015
    20/08/19 15:58:16 ERROR org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3241)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3259)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:470)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1866)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.<init>(EventLoggingListener.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:522)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$1(SparkSession.scala:930)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921)
        at com.walmart.ei.dqa.Utils$.getSparkSession(Utils.scala:47)
        at com.walmart.ei.EntryPoint$.main(EntryPoint.scala:27)
        at com.walmart.ei.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        ... 27 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: shaded.guava.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;J)V
        at shaded.guava.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageReadOptions$Builder.build(GoogleCloudStorageReadOptions.java:224)
        at shaded.guava.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageReadOptions.<clinit>(GoogleCloudStorageReadOptions.java:60)
        at shaded.guava.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemConfiguration.<clinit>(GoogleHadoopFileSystemConfiguration.java:423)
        at shaded.guava.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.<init>(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:227)
        at shaded.guava.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem.<init>(GoogleHadoopFileSystem.java:54)
        ... 32 more
    20/08/19 15:58:16 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@6015a4a5{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:0}
```

This is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.example.ei</groupId>
      <artifactId>ei-ingestion-data</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    
      <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.ei.dqa</groupId>
        <artifactId>dqa-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
      </parent>
    
      <properties>
    
        <spark.version>2.4.4</spark.version>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <shade.version>3.2.0</shade.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <ei.canonical.schema.version>0.32.1</ei.canonical.schema.version>
        <apache.commons.email.version>1.5</apache.commons.email.version>
    <!--    <maven.scala.version>2.15.2</maven.scala.version>-->
        <scalatest.version>3.1.1</scalatest.version>
    <!--    <scalatest.maven.plugin.version>1.0</scalatest.maven.plugin.version>-->
    <!--    <cucumber.version>4.2.0</cucumber.version>-->
    <!--    <scala.tools.version>2.11</scala.tools.version>-->
      </properties>
    
      <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </dependencyManagement>
    
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.walmart.ei.dqa</groupId>
        <artifactId>dqa-spark-utils</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
          <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${spark.version}</version>
    
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
          <version>28.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${spark.version}</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
              <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
              <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-avro_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
    
    <!--    <dependency>-->
    <!--      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>-->
    <!--      <artifactId>spark-avro_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>-->
    <!--      <version>${spark.version}</version>-->
    <!--    </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.walmart.ei</groupId>
          <artifactId>ei-canonical-schema</artifactId>
          <version>${ei.canonical.schema.version}</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
              <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
              <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
              <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-storage -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
              <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    
    <!--    <dependency>-->
    <!--      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>-->
    <!--      <artifactId>kafka_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>-->
    <!--      <version>${kafka.version}</version>-->
    <!--      <exclusions>-->
    <!--        <exclusion>-->
    <!--          <artifactId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</artifactId>-->
    <!--          <groupId>jackson-databind</groupId>-->
    <!--        </exclusion>-->
    <!--      </exclusions>-->
    <!--    </dependency>-->
    <!--    <dependency>-->
    <!--      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>-->
    <!--      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>-->
    <!--      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>-->
    <!--      <scope>test</scope>-->
    <!--    </dependency>-->
    <!--    <dependency>-->
    <!--      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>-->
    <!--      <artifactId>cucumber-scala_${scala.tools.version}</artifactId>-->
    <!--      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>-->
    <!--      <scope>test</scope>-->
    <!--    </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
          <version>${apache.commons.email.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
          <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${scalatest.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
          <artifactId>gcs-connector</artifactId>
          <version>hadoop2-2.0.0</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
              <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    
    
      </dependencies>
    
    
      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
          <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
          </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${shade.version}</version>
            <configuration>
              <relocations>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>com.walmart.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
              </relocations>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <filters>
                    <filter>
                      <artifact>*</artifact>
                      <excludes>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                      </excludes>
                    </filter>
                  </filters>
                  <artifactSet>
                    <excludes>
                      <exclude>org.datanucleus</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                  </artifactSet>
                  <promoteTransitiveDependencies>true</promoteTransitiveDependencies>
                  <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                  <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                      <pattern>com.google</pattern>
                      <shadedPattern>shaded.guava</shadedPattern>
                      <includes>
                        <include>com.google.**</include>
                      </includes>
                      <excludes>
                        <exclude>com.google.common.base.Optional</exclude>
                        <exclude>com.google.common.base.Absent</exclude>
                        <exclude>com.google.common.base.Present</exclude>
                      </excludes>
                    </relocation>
                  </relocations>
                  <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                      <mainClass>com.example.ei.dqa.StructuredStreaming</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                  </transformers>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    
    </project>
```

Comment: it seems like issue with a runtime dependency issue of hadoop ... please make sure you have same version of spark and hadoop in prod cluster as well... and also make sure that you have added inter-compatible 3rd party dependencies with spark and Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably that you have misconfigured dependencies in your application jar.

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: shaded.guava.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;J)` exception points that you shaded and included in your application jar a version of Guava library that is not compatible (i.e. it does not have a required method) with GCSIO library that is a part of GCS connector. To solve this issue you need to make sure that you are using Guava version that is compatible with GCSIO library. For GCS connector 2.0.0 it [should be Guava `28.0-jre`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/2fbaa0420f194f9d1dc964c13f954a87f8032caa/pom.xml#L97).

To inspect dependencies in your `pom.xml` and understand from what dependencies older versions of Guava could be included in your application jar you can use [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/):

```sh
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.google.guava
```

Also, if you are using Spark you should use Hadoop FileSystem that implemented by GCS connector to access Google Cloud Storage (GCS), the same as you will do to access HDFS files, you just need to change FS schema from `hdfs://` to `gs://`. Because of this you should not depend on `gcs-connector` artifact directly, neither you should depend on other GCS clients like `google-cloud-storage` because Dataproc cluster already has [pre-installed GCS connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage#clusters) and you should use through [HCFS interface](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/util/HdfsUtils.html) if you need to access GCS objects directly.